# scrapy: OpenSSL and cryptography binding error in OSX

Tags: python, macos, scrapy

I use `pip` to install `scrapy` and Homebrew to install OpenSSL on my mac.

Importing `scrapy` in Python and run `scrapy --version` are fine, but running the scrapy project causes the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 94, in <module>
    setup_crawler(spider_name, 0, keywords)
  File "search.py", line 58, in setup_crawler
    crawler = Crawler(MySpider, settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.extensions = ExtensionManager.from_crawler(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 56, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 32, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/memusage.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scrapy.mail import MailSender
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/mail.py", line 22, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import defer, reactor, ssl
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/ssl.py", line 59, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 11, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 205, in <module>
    Binding.init_static_locks()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 172, in init_static_locks
    __import__("_ssl")
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

I have run `brew link openssl`, so why do I still get this error?

I have checked the code of the `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py`:

```
# Use Python's implementation if available, importing _ssl triggers
# the setup for this.
__import__("_ssl")
```

But I don't understand what this means.

---

OS: Mac OSX 10.11 El Captian

scrapy version: 1.0.5

pip version: 8.0.3

python version: 2.7

Comment: Could you check if cryptography installed correctly? `pip uninstall cryptography` and `pip install cryptography` to see what will happen. There's chance openssl is not in the default path, so cryptography will not be installed properly as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The cryptography seems not installed properly. homebrewed openssl dependency. Try:

`env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography`